# understanding this timing result

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I got two timings which I do not understand.

```
a = RandomReal[1., {1000, 1000}];
Table[RotateLeft[a, {1, 1}][[1, 1]], {i, 1, 500}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[RotateLeft[a, {1, 1}];, {i, 1, 500}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

which gives

```
{1.02723, Null}
{3.02416, Null}
```

But from the `Trace`, it seems that both doing roughly the same amount of work. Why is there such a huge differece?

another one is

```
Do[(a*1.)[[1, 1]], {i, 1, 2000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[(a*1.)[[1, 1]], {i, 1, 2000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

which gives

```
{11.3509, Null}
{3.5007, Null}
```

Why is there a huge difference between `Table` and `Do`?

Answer (score 2):

<s>Memory. `Table[RotateLeft[a, {1, 1}];, {i, 1, 500}]` requires to allocate and to write $1000 \times 1000 \times 500 \times 8$ bytes for storing the result, while `Table[RotateLeft[a, {1, 1}][[1, 1]], {i, 1, 500}];` requires only $500 \times 8$ bytes. However, I cannot reproduce the timings with Mathematica 12 for macos. My timings are `0.413361` for the former and `0.39489` for the latter.</s>

<s>However, I don't fully understand the difference between `Do` and `Table`. And the relative difference is a bit smaller on my machine. The timings are `1.669` for `Do` and `0.748476` for `Table`. One possible reason could be that the memory for the result of `Table` is allocated one and the BLAS(?) routines that are called by `a*1.` are directly used as return buffer. In contrast, there is a chance that `Do` allocates and deallocates memory for each intermediate result. But I don't know. This issue is probably worth to be submitted to Wolfram Support.</s>

**Edit**

As J.M. suspected, it is about `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength"}]`. Executing

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> 10000}]
```

before the `Do` and `Table` calls makes them equally bad in performance. So for some reason, the `Do` loop is not autocompiled. First I wondered why that is. Then it came to my mind that the intend of using a `Do` loop is typically a side effect that might be infeasible to be handled by a compiled function.

**Edit**

The return value of `RotateLeft[a, {1, 1}];` is `Null` and that cannot be compiled. So `Table[RotateLeft[a, {1, 1}];, {i, 1, 500}];` is evaluated without the JIT-compiler.

Comment: Can you do an experiment where you first evaluate `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> n}]`, where `n` is e.g. larger or smaller than the table's length?

Comment: Hi, Henrik Schumacher. Thank you for answering. But I do not understand why `Table[RotateLeft[a, {1, 1}];, {i, 1, 500}]` would need 1000×1000×500×8, there is `;` after `RotateLeft`, it does not need such a large space to hold result.

Comment: Besides, I found setting "TableCompileLength" -> 10000, makes two Table of RotateLeft the same timing. So it maybe a evidence that memory is not the issue here. But I do not understand, when compileLength is small, the only difference is that the second Table generate a list like {Null, Null, ...} which is unpacked, but that should not account for such a huge timing difference. I used 12.2, this behaviour appears on both windows and linux

Comment: Valid points. I had overlooked the semicolon. It is then probably all about compilation. `Null` cannot be compiled, so auto-compilation for `Table[RotateLeft[a, {1, 1}];, {i, 1, 500}]` does not work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got a better understanding of autocompile now. So `Table` saw each element is returning Null, so the whole Table process is not compiled. But it is still bizarre to me that `RotateLeft` is kernel function, why there would be seconds of speed up after compilation. Generating a list of 500 null  takes less than 1 microsecond. What has autocompilation been speeding up?